# Chrome Remote Desktop with external mouse?

Tags: external-keyboard, remote-access

I've been googling for hours and all I can find are a few years old pages saying the only way to do a right click is double touch on the screen...

Has anyone found any better solution since? Maybe with External Keyboard Helper or some similar app??

Also, there seems to be no way to scroll. I've tried the browser version on Android tablet, and it works faster and you can scroll, but there is absolutely no way to press a right click.

It seems imposible that google would not adress this issue for years, since it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I found an acceptable solution on my Huawei tablet... if I switch to "desktop mode", right mouse click starts working like on PC, so I then connect throug browser client. I don't know if that is possible on other tablets.

Hope this helps anyone.